# Evaluating $\lim_{x\to \infty}\Biggl(\dfrac{(x+1)^x}{x^x\cdot\mathcal{e}}\Biggr)^x$

Tags: limits, problem-solving

I'm stuck in this problem where my answer is repeatedly resulting in**1**, which isn't correct, which is making me doubt my procedure. **Please point out where I went wrong.**
$$\lim_{x\to \infty}\Biggl(\dfrac{(x+1)^x}{x^x\cdot\mathcal{e}}\Biggr)^x=\lim_{x\to \infty}\dfrac{(1+\frac{1}{x})^{x^2}}{\mathcal{e}^x}=\lim_{x\to \infty}\dfrac{\mathcal{e}^{\frac{1}{x}\cdot x^2}}{\mathcal{e}^x}\text{$\Bigl(\because1^{\infty}$ form}\Bigr)$$
$$\lim_{x\to \infty}\dfrac{\mathcal{e}^{\frac{1}{x}\cdot x^2}}{\mathcal{e}^x}=1$$
That's my answer, but it is supposed to be $\dfrac{1}{\sqrt{\mathcal{e}}}$.

Comment: @CheerfulParsnip Won't that again result in 1?

Comment: I deleted my comment since I wasn't sure that's where your confusion was. Right now I'm not seeing how you found $\lim (1+\frac{1}{x})^{x^2}$. This is not $e^{x}$ as your calculation claims.

Comment: Indeed this is your error, it's not the case that $(1+1/x)^{x^2}\sim e^x$.

Comment: @LordSharktheUnknown Could you explain it more why it won't result to $e^x$?

Comment: @UtkarshVerma See my answer.

Comment: @CheerfulParsnip It is $\lim (1+\frac{1}{x})^{x^2}=e^x.$ But we can't use this here.

Comment: @mfl Oh I see. Actually the limit is $\infty$ and as Lord Shark mentions the real question is whether it is asymptotically equivalent to $e^x$.

Comment: @LordSharktheUnknown I still don't get what I did wrong. I do comply with your answer however.

Comment: @CheerfulParsnip Yes. $\lim_{x\to \infty}\dfrac{(1+\frac{1}{x})^{x^2}}{\mathcal{e}^x}=\dfrac{\lim_{x\to \infty} (1+\frac{1}{x})^{x^2}}{\lim_{x\to \infty} e^x}$ makes no sense.You can't take the limit in the numerator and leave the denominator invariant. And then take the limit again.

Comment: @mfk: Even saying $\lim (1+\frac{1}{x})^{x^2})=e^x$ makes no sense since it still depends on $x$.

Comment: You seem to be doing $$\lim_{y\to \infty}\lim_{x\to \infty}\Biggl(\dfrac{(x+1)^x}{x^x\cdot\mathcal{e}}\Biggr)^y=1$$

Comment: @KeithMcClary I did squeeze the powers inside to solve them together. How does that mean I'm solving them differently?

Comment: Are you familiar with functions $f(u,v)$ that have different limits at $(0,0)$  depending on how you approach the origin, eg. $\lim_{u\to 0}f(u,u) \ne \lim_{u\to 0}\lim_{v\to 0}f(u,v)$? This is the situation in the above with $u=1/x, v=1/y$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is an explanation why the OP was wrong.

Since$$(1+\frac{1}{x})= \mathcal{e}^{\frac{1}{x}}$$ is not true, therefore we can't be sure whether$$\lim_{x\to \infty}\dfrac{(1+\frac{1}{x})^{x^2}}{\mathcal{e}^x}=\lim_{x\to \infty}\dfrac{\mathcal{e}^{\frac{1}{x}\cdot x^2}}{\mathcal{e}^x}$$
is true or not.

---

**Note**:

If we want to use the theorem

> $$\lim_{x\to a}f(x)^{g(x)}=\mathcal{e}^{\lim_{x\to a}(f(x)-1)g(x)} \;\;\text{ if }\; f(a) \to 1 \;\;\text{ and } \;g(a) \to \infty$$

we have to write$$\lim_{x\to\infty}\dfrac{(1+\frac{1}{x})^{x^2}}{\mathcal{e}^x}=\lim_{x\to\infty}\left(\dfrac{1+\frac{1}{x}}{\mathcal{e}^{1/x}}\right)^{x^2}$$
instead of
$$\lim_{x\to \infty}\dfrac{(1+\frac{1}{x})^{x^2}}{\mathcal{e}^x}=\lim_{x\to \infty}\dfrac{\mathcal{e}^{\frac{1}{x}\cdot x^2}}{\mathcal{e}^x}.$$

Comment: This doesn't acquire 1^infty form that is why you're able to say this. I used (1+1/x)^(x^2) which attains 1^infinity form.

Comment: @UtkarshVerma What is the theorem about $1^\infty$ form that you used?

Comment: $$\lim_{x\to a}f(x)^{g(x)}=\mathcal{e}^{\lim_{x\to\infty}(f(x)-1)g(x)}$$. If $f(a) \to 1$ and $g(a)\to \infty$.

Comment: @UtkarshVerma If we apply your theorem, then $$\lim_{x\to\infty}\dfrac{(1+\frac{1}{x})^{x^2}}{\mathcal{e}^x}=\lim_{x\to\infty}\left(\dfrac{1+\frac{1}{x}}{\mathcal{e}^{1/x}}\right)^{x^2}$$, we have to consider the whole thing behind the $\lim$ sign.

Comment: Ah, got it. I can't distribute the limit since the denominator's limit is non-existant. Thanks. Please include it in your answer. :)

Comment: @UtkarshVerma OK, I have edited my answer.

Answer (score 6):

The logarithm of your expression is
$$x^2\ln\left(1+\frac1x\right)-x
=x^2\left(\frac1x-\frac1{2x^2}+O(x^{-3})\right)-x
=-\frac12+O(x^{-1})\to-\frac12$$
as $x\to\infty$.

Answer (score 3):

A little more generally,
let
$f(a)
=\lim_{x\to \infty}\Biggl(\dfrac{(x+a)^x}{x^x\cdot\mathcal{e}}\Biggr)^x
$.
Then

$\begin{array}\\
g(a)
&=\ln(f(a))\\
&=\lim_{x\to \infty}x\ln\dfrac{(x+a)^x}{x^x\cdot\mathcal{e}}\\
&=\lim_{x\to \infty}x\left(\ln\dfrac{(x+a)^x}{x^x}-1\right)\\
&=\lim_{x\to \infty}\left(x\ln\dfrac{(x+a)^x}{x^x}-x\right)\\
&=\lim_{x\to \infty}\left(x^2\ln\dfrac{(x+a)}{x}-x\right)\\
&=\lim_{x\to \infty}\left(x^2\ln(1+\frac{a}{x})-x\right)\\
&=\lim_{x\to \infty}\left(x^2(\frac{a}{x}-\frac{a^2}{2x^2}+O(\frac1{x^3}))-x\right)\\
&=\lim_{x\to \infty}\left(ax-\frac{a^2}{2}+O(\frac1{x})-x\right)\\
&=\lim_{x\to \infty}\left((a-1)x-\frac{a^2}{2}+O(\frac1{x})\right)\\
\end{array}
$

If $a=1$
(as in this problem),
$g(1)
=-\frac12$.

If $a \ne 1$,
then
$\lim_{x \to \infty} (g(a)-(a-1)x)
=-\frac{a^2}{2}
$.